# Ruby: Separating Multiple Returns

Tags: ruby, return-value

In my example below, 2 and 3 are being returned as an array. Is there a shortcut to split the values in the array to assign to different variables without having to manually do something like `two = answers[0]`?

```
def returnThreeValues
  return 1, returnTwoValues
end

def returnTwoValues
  return 2, 3
end

def shortcut
  one, two, three = returnThreeValues

  puts "one: " + one.to_s
  puts "two: " + two.to_s
  puts "three: " + three.to_s
end

shortcut()
```

Outputs:

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-linux]

one: 1
two: [2, 3]
three:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @matthew says. Or this:

```
def returnThreeValues
  return 1, *returnTwoValues
end
```

Comment: I actually like this one better :)

Comment: Agreed. Is that just a shortcut for flatten or is it a different function with a similar outcome?

Comment: @buddingprogrammer: it's called a "splat operator".

Answer (score 2):

The issue here that your `returnThreeValues` method is returning an array with a value and an inner array which is:

```
[1, [2, 3]]
```

and you are attempting assignment to three variables. To fix your code it would have to be:

```
one, two, three = returnThreeValues.flatten
```

or you can change the method itself

```
def returnThreeValues
  [1, returnTwoValues].flatten
end
```

which would change the return value of `returnThreeValues` to now be `[1, 2, 3]`

Worth noting that you don't need the explicit `return` in your methods as well.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: `one, (two, three) = [1, [2, 3]]` arguably reads better and is more versatile, as you might want to write `one, (two, (three, four)) = [1, [2,[3,4]]]` or `one, (two, arr) = [1, [2,[3,4]]]`, neither of which could be done using `flatten`. Readers, see [multiple assignment and array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment).